# How to replace string if some characters are the same on pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an Import/export trade data of the country. From initial data, some country names have a weird symbol: `��`.
For this reason, I am struggling to replace those strings.

Currently, I am replacing country names to their 3 letter country code. `For example, China = CHI, Russian Federation = RUS.` My code works fine for most of the country names.

```
Except: C��ina, ��etnam, Turk��, T��rkey, Uzbekist��n, Uzb��kistan etc.
```

I can manually format it for the first time, however, this data is updating every month, and size is now almost 2 billion rows.

```
for i,j in all_3n.items():

    df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace(j,i)
```

This is the code how I am replacing now. Furthermore, how to replace the whole string, not only the founded string?
For example, for lookup I have Russia and string in the database is Russian Federation, it is returning me RUSn Federation. any ideas on how to overcome these two challenges? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried defining the 'encoding' parameter when reading the file to get rid of the 'weird symbols' all together? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @Mandera these symbols are existing in the original excel file

Answer (score 1):

You should use the code `'\uFFFD'` for the replacement character �:

```
df['Country'] = df['Country'].str.replace('\uFFFD', '')
```